# Alguem poderia me auxiliar a trabalhar struct com vetores e função, não estou sabendo na hora de passar os dados

Tags: c, array, funções, struct

```
typedef struct
{ int cod, num_hab;
  char sigla_esta[5], estado[30], cidade[30];
}Cidade;

main()
{
    //Variaveis 
    Cidade cidades[max];
    Estado estados[max];
    Pais paises[max];
    int op, i, posl, aux;
    int cc = 0, ce = 0, cp = 0; // um contador para cada vetor 
    char auxSt[50];
    //Funções Declaradas
    void CadCidade();
    
    
    
    do
    {   
        i=0;    //Zerando o I para nao gerar lixo da memoria depois de utilizar
        //Função menu
        menu(&op);

        switch(op){
            case 1: 
                
                CadCidade(&cc,&cidades);
```

A função está assim, mas não está funcionando

```
void CadCidade(int *ccF, Cidade *cid){
    
    //system("cls");    //Limpa a tela
    printf("\tInsira a cidade\n");
        
    printf("Digite o codigo da cidade: ");
    scanf("%d", &(*cid)[ccF].cod);
    fflush(stdin);
```

Comment: Como `[ccF]` é um índice creio que deveria utilizar `[*ccF]` já que declarou o parâmetro `ccF` como ponteiro..

Answer (score 0):

1. Creio que as Structs (tipos) `Estado estados[max];` e `Pais paises[max];` não foram declarados, assim como a variavel Max, que deveria ser declarada e inicializada antes de ser utilizada no Main, mesmo que seja por um #DEFINE no cabeçalho do código.

2.Função `void CadCidade();` não precisa ser tipada no Main

3. Não compreendo a função DO usada ali, porém como existe o comentário sobre o i abaixo, imagino que seja usada como repetição, porém como não vejo a condição do WHILE nem condição de parada, pode ser que tenha um loop infinito.

4.Função `menu(&op);` não tem declaração, se essa é a declaração, precisa conter tipo da função.

5. O uso do `scanf("%d", &(*cid)[ccF].cod);` me parece um acesso errado do ponteiro, pois você requisita o endereço da variável ponteiro, e não o conteúdo dela, que é o que você quer acessar, creio que a sintaxe correta seria `scanf("%d",&cid[ccf].cod);`